# Get all next siblings of element

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to get all next siblings of a element? Not just next one and not siblings before it?

This was the way I found, but is there a jQuery selector for it?

```
$('.someclass').click(function () {
    var chosenOne = $(this);
    $('.someclass').removeClass('extraclass');
    chosenOne.parent().find('.someclass').each(function () {
        var el = $(this).index();
        if (el >= chosenOne.index()) {
            $(this).addClass('extraclass');
        }
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yMHMf/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall) method was made for this:

```
chosenone.nextAll(".someclass").addBack().addClass("extraclass")
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yMHMf/2/)

Comment: There it was. Ok! Thank you Kevin! Then I just need to add the class for the clicked one also.

Comment: `.addBack()` replaced `.andSelf()` in jquery 1.9

Comment: Ok. Thank you for fast answer. Accepted and +1